# What is the difference between IRQ Handler and Callback function?

Tags: embedded, interrupt, stm32f4

We are using STM32F429I and trying to use Timers(TIM2 and TIM5) by diffferent ways. 
In our code after we enable the Timers and call;

```
HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim5);
```

We can update our variables by via calling **TIM5_IRQHandler** function.
We have noticed that same process has been done by **HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback** function.

So our question is: Is there any difference between these two function?

Comment: The question in the title is generic, while the body refers to a specific situation.  Which of these do you actually need an answer to?

Comment: What do you mean by "calling TIM5_IRQHandler"?  You should not be "calling" an interrupt handler.  The interrupt vector table should be setup to point to the interrupt handler so that the interrupt handler runs when the interrupt occurs.  In the STM32Cube system the generic interrupt handler calls the callback function.  You can choose to implement the callback function with application specific stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the STM32Cube framework `TIM5_IRQHandler()` calls `HAL_TIM_IRQHandler()` which calls `HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback()` (among a number of other event callbacks).

`HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback()` has "weak-linkage", meaning a do-nothing default is defined that you can override by defining your own implementation.

A disadvantage of using the HAL in this way is that it adds overhead to the interrupt handler and because the same `HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback()` is invoked for all timers, additional code is required to determine which timer invoked the callback if you are to handle more than one timer.  When such timers are for entirely different purposes, that can lead for a poor design from a low-coupling/high-cohesion point of view.

Where absolute deterministic behaviour and minimal interrupt time are critical, you might want to avoid this "built-for-comfort" infrastructure and handle the timer interrupt directly.  Generally that will also lead to a better design (lower coupling/greater cohesion).

If you are making extensive use of the STM32Cube and CMSIS frameworks and middleware, then circumventing the HAL may cause issues in utilising that codebase however.

Comment: So we should call the TIM5_IRQHandler() directly instead of call the PeriodElapsedCallBack()? Or we should implement our timer function for better utilising solutions?

Comment: @TürkerBerkeYıldırım That would be a matter of opinion so off-topic.  My answer is intended to at least make that an informed opinion.  I would say that if you are committed to a solution using the HAL, the path of least resistance would be to use it in the manner intended.  Personally I am of the opinion that the whole ST Cube/HAL, is a horribly designed mismatched collection of bloatware designed to lock you into ST's parts and require you to use the larger, faster, more expensive parts than you would otherwise need.  But that's just an opinion.

Comment: I see sir, we understood your answer. Thank you a lot :) Additionaly, I think we should learn to implement our Timer driver.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are differences between them. `TIM5_IRQHandler()` handles all interrupts triggered by `htim5`. For example there are callbacks like half complete, PWM pulse finished, timer error callbacks etc. for these different timer events.